# Plot average of y values for every x value

Tags: python, matplotlib, group-by

I have a df which is unsorted and has around 750,000 rows. Now I want to group the df by `mrwSmpVWi` and get the average of my `mrwSmpP`. For example: I have 2,000 `mrwSmpP` values for  `mrwSmpVWi = 3` I want to get the average of the 2,000 values. If I have one y value for every x value I want to plot it by another group which is the column `Seriennummer`.

```
for number in df.groupby('mrwSmpVWi'):
    df['m'] = df['mrwSmpP'].mean()

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(30,15))

for name, group in df.groupby('Seriennummer'):
    group.plot(x="mrwSmpVWi", y="m", ax=ax, marker='o', linestyle='', ms=12, label =name)
    

plt.show()
```

If I do it like this. I will just get a straight line for my average values.

[image]

This is a part of my df:

[image]

**EDIT:**

I changed it this way:

```
#for number in df.groupby('mrwSmpVWi'):
df['m'] = df.groupby('mrwSmpVWi')['mrwSmpP'].mean()
```

It doesn't make a change if I do it with or without the for loop. I will get this diagram:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are overwritting the mean column on each iteration of the first loop. Also, to save a mean on each value of the dataframe, you need to use a merge. Try:

```
df = df.merge(df.groupby('mrwSmpVWi')["mrwSmpP"].mean().rename("m").reset_index(), on="mrwSmpVWi", how="left")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It changed but still not what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: @1lk4 I don't get what is now wrong, please describe what is missing from the plot.

Comment: I just see the dots from one serial number and the values are wrong. I hvae x values which reach 30 and in that diagram they stop at 3. I also tried it with two for loops. But still no change. `for name, group in df.groupby('Seriennummer'):
    for number in df.groupby('mrwSmpVWi'):
        df['m'] = df.groupby('mrwSmpVWi')['mrwSmpP'].mean()`

Comment: @1lk4 ok, it seemed the values were not correctly saved, I edited the answer.

Comment: It says that .agg needs two values so I edited `.agg("mean", axis="1")` but then it get a `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 8, placement implies 1`

Comment: @1lk4 That's because we use a different version of pandas, I reedited the answer.